# Closing a div when clicking on a button which is inside of the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Make so simple to answer but it is unable for me to make it work...
The title says it all so maybe someone can help me out.

```
_doc.on('click','.settings',function() {
    $('.icon-bar').fadeIn(200);
});

_doc.on('click','.close_btn',function(e) {
    $('.icon-bar').hide(e.currentTarget.id);
    $('.icon-bar').fadeOut(200);
});
```

The button who opens it is called 'settings' and the one who should be closing the div is called 'close_btn'.

Comment: Can you post your html as well ?

Comment: Your syntax for calling `hide()` is incorrect. I'd suggest you remove that line completely to be honest, as it's pretty redundant if you want the element to `fadeOut()`

Comment: create a demo that is clear enough to explain what you are trying to do what is expected output and what is the issue. Post your HTML as well.

Comment: Do you have multiple divs like this? Are you trying to make each close button close their parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain.
When user clicks on button our event will trigger

```
_doc.on('click','.close_btn',function(e) {

});
```

Here we can use closest()

```
_doc.on('click','.close_btn',function(e) {
   jQuery(this).closest('div').hide();
});
```

If we want to use class selector

```
_doc.on('click','.close_btn',function(e) {
   jQuery(this).closest('.parent_div').hide();
});
```

It will hide button and parent element with class="parent_div".
Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: well done my friend, you did the job, last thing what is needed is: When i open the div with the button: 'settings', it opens multiple 'icon-bar' s but i only need specificly one i clicked on, i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: in that case you need to put things in a specific order
`<div><div class='settings'>Settings</div><div class='icon-bar'></div></div>`
In this case your use `jQuery(this).siblings('.icon-bar').show()` or `jQuery(this).closest('div').find('.icon-bar').show();` you can also use child instead of find

Comment: I'm really glad u helped me out, it was indeed the last one, thank you alot and have  a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    //to remove completely from page
        $('.button_class').parents('.parent-div-class').remove();
    // to hide only
     $('.button_class').parents('.parent-div-class').fadeOut('fast');
```

parents function will select outter wrap div of this button 
like

```
         <div class="parent-div-class">
            <div>
               <button attribse></button>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/egocgn9y/) ?

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/egocgn9y/

css :

```
div{
  border : 2px solid green;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left : 2px;
}
div input[type="button"]{
  float:right;
}
```

html :

```
<div>
  <input id="btnClose1" type="button" Value="X">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="btnClose2" type="button" Value="X">
</div>
```

js :

```
$('#btnClose1').on("click", function(){
  this.parentElement.remove();                 
});
$('#btnClose2').on("click", function(){
  this.parentElement.remove();               
});
```